# Get span class dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to get span value from dropdown. I can get the selected value from the following line:

```
   $(".home_button").click(function(){ 
   alert($('.selected_item.select-school').text())
});
```

But the problem it returns the text inside the span class. So if a user not select a value it returns 'Select a School' which i want to avoid. How do i get the exact id or value from li and put it into span class?

```
<div class="school_area form_item">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-education item_icon">
         </span>
            <div class="count">
              <span class="selected_item select-school">Select School
              </span>
              <span class="down_icon glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down">
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="form_item_dropdown">
              <div class="dropdown_wrapper">

                <li class="school" onclick="dropdown(this)">
                  <span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-education">
                  </span>
                  <span id="1" class="school_title item_title">ABC
                  </span>
                </li>
                <li class="school" onclick="dropdown(this)">
                  <span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-education">
                  </span>
                  <span id="2" class="school_title item_title">EFG
                  </span>
                </li>
                <li class="school" onclick="dropdown(this)">
                  <span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-education">
                  </span>
                  <span id="3" class="school_title item_title">WOW
                  </span>
                </li>
              </div>
            </div>
       </div>

    <button class="home_button">Store
    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do like so:

```js
$('.home_button').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('li.school > .school_title.activated').each(function(){
        console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});

$('li.school > .school_title').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('activated');
});
```

```css
.activated {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="school_area form_item">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-education item_icon">
 </span>
    <div class="count">
      <span class="selected_item select-school">Select School
      </span>
      <span class="down_icon glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down">
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="form_item_dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown_wrapper">

        <li class="school">
          <span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-education">
          </span>
          <span id="1" class="school_title item_title">ABC
          </span>
        </li>
        <li class="school">
          <span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-education">
          </span>
          <span id="2" class="school_title item_title">EFG
          </span>
        </li>
        <li class="school">
          <span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-education">
          </span>
          <span id="3" class="school_title item_title">WOW
          </span>
        </li>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button class="home_button">Store</button>
```

But honestly this is bad. I don't know about if you can add only on `.school-item` or multiple. Either way to use `<form>` and **values** you should use  combined with [checkbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox) or [radio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio).

Comment: There is a button under it so when i tried to submit the form i need that value.

Comment: @User57 your comment is the only thing on this page mentioning a "button". Under what is it? How does it look like?

Comment: @User57 well that does not really work. You talk about a "form" but you don't have a form. You might want to use [checkbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox) or [radio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) and that should be inside a form. Depending if you can add only a single or multiple schools...

Answer (score 0):

I restructured your HTML a bit to deal for the sake of scalibility.  Now the code scans for the `.form_item_dropdown` and then sets the input inside the form wtih whatever li you clicked last.

```js
$(".form_item_dropdown li").click(function () {
  $(this).closest(".form_item_dropdown").children("input").first().val($(this).attr("value"));
});

$(".home_button").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($("#myFrom").serialize());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myFrom">
    <div class="school_area form_item">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-education item_icon">
         </span>
            <div class="count">
              <span class="selected_item select-school">Select School
              </span>
              <span class="down_icon glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down">
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="form_item_dropdown">
              <input type="hidden" name="school" value="1">
              <div class="dropdown_wrapper">
                <li value="1">
                  <span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-education">
                  </span>
                  <span class="school_title item_title">ABC
                  </span>
                </li>
                <li value="2">
                  <span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-education">
                  </span>
                  <span class="school_title item_title">EFG
                  </span>
                </li>
                <li value="3">
                  <span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-education">
                  </span>
                  <span class="school_title item_title">WOW
                  </span>
                </li>
              </div>
            </div>
       </div>

    <button class="home_button">Store
    </button>
</form>
```